# Roles for GenericPrincipal are being lost

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am attempting to set up roles on my dynamic data website, but am encountering an issue.

Between the time I set up by Generic Principal, and when the default page is hit the roles of my principal are lost. The principal is still listed as the context.user, for when I debug my session and inspect the context.user object the user I set up is the user I set up; but all roles related to that user seem to be lost.

This is how I am going about it.

Login page

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string[] masterServiceResult;

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsAuthenticUser(login_email.Text, login_password.Text))
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, masterServiceResult[0], DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, masterServiceResult[2], FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string encryptedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedCookie);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(masterServiceResult[0], true));

    }
}

private bool IsAuthenticUser(string email, string password)
{
    MembershipService membershipService = new MembershipService();
    var result = membershipService.GetUserAndRoleFromCredentials(email, password);

    //result is an array with userName, userId, error(bool) as string, and error message if any
    if (bool.Parse(result[3]) == false)
    {
        masterServiceResult = result;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Then in Global.asax I have attached to the AuthenticateRequest event

```
void Global_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        SetupRoles();
}

private void SetupRoles()
{
    if (Context.User != null)
    {
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

        HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

        if (authCookie == null)
            return;

        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });

        IIdentity fi = Context.User.Identity;
        IPrincipal pi = new GenericPrincipal(fi, roles);


        Context.User = pi;

        //sets the application principal to use the logged on user account
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;

        // sanity check to ensure the role was set up.
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            int i = 0; // debug line
        }
    }
}
```

At this point everything is working as intended; my test account is now set as the context.user, the Current Principal user is set as the current user, and the users role of Admin is causing the "int i=0" debug line to be hit. However once the default page Page_Load is hit this is no longer the case.

Default page. Updated 01/03/12 to show another test case.
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.IList visibleTables = MetaModel.Default.VisibleTables;

```
    // this line comes back as false, though at this point the user name is the same.
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        int i = 0;
    }

    // the next 4 lines of code is a work around I can do to retrieve the roles from the ticket.
    string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
    HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    // this line of code will correctly show the users role
    string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });

    foreach (var table in MetaModel.Default.Tables)
    {
        var permissions = ((MetaTable)table).GetTablePermissions(roles);
        if (permissions.Contains(TablePermissionsAttribute.Permissions.DenyRead))
            visibleTables.Remove(table);
    }

    if (visibleTables.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("There are no accessible tables. Make sure that at least one data model is registered in Global.asax and scaffolding is enabled or implement custom pages.");
    }
    Menu1.DataSource = visibleTables;
    Menu1.DataBind();
}
```

*Updated: I am a able to get the roles for the user rom the authentication ticket, and the principal is correct, but I am baffled as to why the User.IsInRole line fails.

Comment: Have you debugged `SetupRoles` for the second request (when you hit the default page load) - check if user comes as authenticated, if yes, whether roles are read from authentication ticket etc. Also check in page_load whether the user object is the generic principal set up by you (can be done by say modifying the identity name while setting it). The line `Roles.GetRolesForUser()` will always return empty for you because it uses underlying ASP.NET roles provider and you are not using that but rather a custom implementation to associate roles.

Comment: For all requests following the initial the user is authenticated and the principal is the same as the one I set up. I understand why Roles.GetRolesForUser() comes back empty, but I do not understand why the check for IsInRole is failing.

Comment: have you checked if roles embedded within auth ticket are correct? Have you inspected principal object to see if inner roles field is set up correctly? If nothing works, then simply roll your own `IPrincipal` implementation - at least, you would be in control of IsInRole implementation.

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and implemented my own Role Provider. Thank you for your suggestions.